# Unable to lock screen on Ubuntu LiveCD

Tags: ubuntu, screensaver

I go to System Settings -> Screen and there are three options. "Turn off after", "Lock" and "Lock screen after". The last two are grayed out.

Any ideas as to why and how I can unlock them?

I've already created a password for the currently logged in account with passwd...

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu and which window manager does you LiveCD have?

Answer (score 3):

Locking the screen when there is no password makes little sense and also makes it impossible to unlock it. At least that used to be the case in 2006, when locking got disabled by default on LiveCD's.

According to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-screensaver/+bug/30118), locking the screen *should* get enabled automatically when you create a password. Either the information is outdated or you discovered a bug.

On Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity/GNOME, you can enable locking the screen with the following command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.lockdown disable-lock-screen false
```

Comment: I've been using 11.04. Figured it had to be me doing something wrong lol - maybe not! Thanks!